# what is the equivalent perl and python code for unix command "mdb hostname"

Tags: python, perl, shell, unix, solaris

What is the equivalent perl and python code for unix command `mdb hostname` 
This command gives all the details of the host(machine name)?

One way is to run this unix command embedded with perl/python script and get the details, but is there any existing module that provides this functionality?

Comment: No such command (`mdb`) on my Linux box.  Maybe we can help better if we know which information is vital for you.  Processor/core count?  RAM size?  Network specifics?  Load?

Comment: And it probably would be helpful to know on what Unix you are—Linux, Solaris, BSD, …?

Comment: Solaris. It works on solaris

Comment: Thank you.  And what about my first question?  Which information is the one you are looking for?  Very likely in Python and Perl the information gathered by `mdb` can be gathered by several different modules and routines.  The hostname for example in Python would be `import socket; socket.gethostname()`.

Comment: The expected output is the whole lot of details like .. Os_system, version, kernel version, cpu , model,site ..... just run the above command on solaris machine ... u'll get to know... Exact requirement is name of the site

Comment: I have no Solaris, but I could help you with Python if you helped me help you.

Comment: `mdb hostname` runs the `hostname` command under the `mdb` debugger - are you sure that's the command you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always call the `mdb` command in Python like this:

```
import subprocess

mdbOutput = subprocess.check_output([ 'mdb', 'hostname' ])
```

Then you have the output of `mdb` in the variable `mdbOutput` and can parse it yourself.  But since I have no idea what it looks like (you should post that), I have no clue how to go on now.